# Develop for stm32 on beaglebone

Tags: beagleboneblack, stm32, beagleboard

is it possible to compile stm32 code on beaglebone (possibly black)?
As it seems platform has to have access to arm-none-eabi-gcc to be able to compile for stm32?

Comment: one question. here you are talking about cross compiling code for stm32 on your beaglebone instead of a PC , is that right? just checking.
I think the other answer thought you meant  use the same source to compile for both CPUs.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, yes you can.

In order to compile code for stm32 family of mcus you would need a cross-compiler. if you run linux on your beaglebone board you can simply download premade toolchain for your distribution. if you dont find any, you would just build a compiler from source by specifying host and target.

https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler#Preparing_for_the_build this article will help you build a gcc cross compiler for every supported target and host. it takes less then 15 mins.

Few things to note here, once you build your cross compiler, you wont have any kind of libc shiped with it. so get one on github (there are few). your options would be libc or libc-nano (which talks for it self). And from there you will be able to compile code for your stm32 mcu.

For example i ran ubuntu server on my beaglebone black, so in order to compile for stm32 on that, i installed armv7-A gcc compiler, so i can compile for beaglebone it self. then i downloaded source at https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads compile the source and you will have an official arm toolchain for microcontrollers.